# How to set up cron job in cpanel to execute import functionality of my theme

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

How do I set up a cron job in cpanel to execute import functionality of my theme?

I have following field in my cpanel advance cron job: Command to run, Common options(s), Minute(s), Hour(s), Day(s), Month(s), Weekday(s).

What location do I have to give in command to run field? Is it the location of wp-cron.php or location of the php file that will import csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Which file you want to execute through cron? In location tab you will have to add full path of that file which you want to execute.